# Install packages to anaconda from the local system

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a python3 package that is distributed in .deb files, so my local system will always have the "correct" version. How can I tell conda to install/upgrade from my local dist-packages?

Comment: if i got you right instead of `python setup.py install` use `python setup.py develop`it will always look after your local files

Comment: conda can only install conda packages. If you built them with 'python setup.py sdist' you can point 'pip install' to that  file and it will install it in you anaconda environment.